# How can I use tabs and pages in one application?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, mobile, ionic4

Is it possible to use tabs with pages?

I made an [example](https://github.com/StekolschikovV/ionic-children-route-error). It has the following structure:

- [main](https://github.com/StekolschikovV/ionic-children-route-error/tree/master/src/app/main) (page)
- [tabs](https://github.com/StekolschikovV/ionic-children-route-error/tree/master/src/app/tabs) (use as a container)
- ---> [app-routing.module.ts](https://github.com/StekolschikovV/ionic-children-route-error/blob/master/src/app/app-routing.module.ts) (routing for tabs)
- ---> [home](https://github.com/StekolschikovV/ionic-children-route-error/tree/master/src/app/tabs/home) (tab)
- ---> [contacts](https://github.com/StekolschikovV/ionic-children-route-error/tree/master/src/app/tabs/contact) (tab)
- ---> [details](https://github.com/StekolschikovV/ionic-children-route-error/tree/master/src/app/tabs/detail) (tab)
- ---> [about](https://github.com/StekolschikovV/ionic-children-route-error/tree/master/src/app/tabs/about) (tab)

If I use tabs as the default route, everything works(in [app-routing.module.ts](https://github.com/StekolschikovV/ionic-children-route-error/blob/master/src/app/app-routing.module.ts)).

```
const routes: Routes = [
  // { path: '', loadChildren: './main/main.module#MainPageModule' },
  { path: '', loadChildren: './tabs/tabs.module#TabsPageModule' },
];
```

If I use the default route for the main page, then an error will appear when switching to tabs(in [app-routing.module.ts](https://github.com/StekolschikovV/ionic-children-route-error/blob/master/src/app/app-routing.module.ts)).

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', loadChildren: './main/main.module#MainPageModule' },
  { path: 'tabs', loadChildren: './tabs/tabs.module#TabsPageModule' },
];
```

> core.js:9110 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match
>   any routes. URL Segment: 'tabs/home' Error: Cannot match any routes.
>   URL Segment: 'tabs/home'

How can I use tabs and pages in one application?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add

```
RouterModule.forChild([
      {
        path: '',
        component: TabsPage
      }
    ])
```

To your tabs.module.ts in the imports sections.
Otherwise the router doesn't know which page of the Tab Module to Render

Comment: Mehdi, I tried your option, it gives me an error (core.js:9110 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'tabs/home'). Added your version on git.

Comment: I was able to run your project and main page was launch at the root level. It looks fine to me